# Is there a better way to iterate through an object of unknown depth than using map statements nested to the maximum possible depth?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, nested, iteration

I have nested employee objects of different, unknown depths. Each object has a `children` property, which is an array of the employee objects who report to that employee. These child objects have the same attributes as the top level object and may or may not have employee objects in their own `children` property.

I need to go through each employee object's array of employee objects and add each of those objects to one of two different arrays, depending on whether the object has other employee objects in it's own "children" property. These arrays are also properties of the employee objects. Employees with empty "children" arrays will be added to their parent employee's `nonManagersUnder` array, while those with objects in their `children` array will be added to the `managersUnder` array.

The nested employee objects look like this:

```
 {
                id: "n1",
                "isActive": true,
                age: 38,
                name: "Barb Smith",
                "phone": "+1 (882) 547-3581",
                "hired": "2016-08-08T12:46:19 +07:00",
                children: [
                  {
                      id: "n10",
                      "isActive": true,
                      age: 37,
                      name: "Elsie MacDonald",
                      "phone": "+1 (958) 558-2389",
                      "hired": "2015-08-15T04:44:49 +07:00",
                      children: [
                        
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      id: "n11",
                      "isActive": true,
                      age: 29,
                      name: "Peter Chen",
                      "phone": "+1 (881) 574-3927",
                      "hired": "2015-02-16T12:11:11 +08:00",
                      children: [
                        
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      id: "n12",
                      "isActive": true,
                      age: 32,
                      name: "Ty Wilder",
                      "phone": "+1 (990) 506-2830",
                      "hired": "2019-09-17T06:29:16 +07:00",
                      children: [
                        
                      ]
                    }
}
```

This is a very simple example since I didn't want to put something several hundred lines long in my post, but the structure is the same. Just imagine that each of the secondary employee objects has its own children.

You'll notice that the `nonManagersUnder` and `managersUnder` arrays are not attributes of the employee objects to start with. That is because in my current solution they are dynamically assigned.

Here is that solution:

```
countManagers = (employee) => {
  let midManagers = []
  let nonManagers = []
  employee.children.map(child =>{
      if(child.children.length == 0) {
          nonManagers.push(child);
      }else {
          midManagers.push(child);
          child.children.map(grandChild => {
              if(grandChild.children.length == 0){
                  nonManagers.push(grandChild);
              }else {
                  midManagers.push(grandChild);
                  grandChild.children.map(greatGrand => {
                      if(greatGrand.children.length == 0){
                          nonManagers.push(greatGrand)
                      } else {
                          midManagers.push(greatGrand);
                          greatGrand.children.map(grand3 => {
                             if(grand3.children.length==0){
                                 nonManagers.push(grand3);
                             } else {
                                 midManagers.push(grand3);
                                 grand3.children.map(grand4 => {
                                     if(grand4.children.length==0){
                                         nonManagers.push(grand4);
                                     } else {
                                         midManagers.push(grand4);
                                     }
                                 })
                             }
                               
                          })
                      }
                  })
              }
          })
      }
  })
  console.log(midManagers);
  // console.log(nonManagers);
  employee.managersUnder = (midManagers);
  employee.nonManagersUnder=(nonManagers)
}
```

As you can see, it is simply nested map operators and some conditionals, nested to the maximum depth an employee object can be nested. This solution does work, but is very ugly and I'm almost certain there is a better way of doing this. A better solution would work for an object of any depth. This only works for objects where the depth is equal to or less than the number of nested map operators.

Comment: recursion FTW!!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to refresh some recursion stuffs and came out with a solution for you query.

```
const values = [{
  id: "n1",
  children: [{
      id: "n10",
      children: [{
        id: "n100",
        children: []
      }, ]
    },
    {
      id: "n11",
      children: []
    },
    {
      id: "n12",
      children: []
    }
  ]
}]

const getAllManagers = (employees) => {
  return employees.reduce((acc, emp) => {
    return acc.concat(emp.children.length > 0 ? [emp, ...getAllManagers(emp.children)] : [])
  }, [])
}

const getAllNonManagers = (employees) => {
  return employees.reduce((acc, emp) => {
    return acc.concat(emp.children.length > 0 ? getAllNonManagers(emp.children) : emp)
  }, [])
}

console.log("Managers: ", getAllManagers(values))
console.log("NonManagers:", getAllNonManagers(values))
```